# When using a dependency property in uwp, how can I tell the difference between default value and assigned value

Tags: c#, uwp

When using a dependency property in uwp, how can I tell the difference between default value and assigned value

I have used this cases in dependencypropertyhelper for wpf, but this is not available uwp.

Can anyone one share a solution for this in uwp?

Answer (score 2):

You could compare the value returned by the `ReadValue` method with `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, e.g.:

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
if (textBlock.ReadLocalValue(TextBlock.TextProperty) ==  DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
{
    //property not set...
}
```

Comment: can you please tell another solution possible for this

Comment: not consider the set value when dependency property value set cases,

Comment: The set value is returned by the property.